# I am new to flutter app development. Got handover of the flutter project and tried to run, but getting Build Failed Exception by terminal command

Tags: java, android, flutter, build, runtime-error

My app was working fine and all of a sudden this error popped up and no longer works

Launching lib\main.dart on Redmi Note 9S in debug mode...
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.

> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.Workers$ActionFacade
> Android resource linking failed
> C:\Users\abumo.gradle\caches\transforms-2\files-2.1\e8b87230ecc8f4137f972d2f499610c1\play-services-ads-lite-20.0.0\AndroidManifest.xml:27:5-43:15: AAPT: error: unexpected element  found in .

- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 2m 46s
The built failed likely due to AndroidX incompatibilities in a plugin. The tool is about to try using Jetfier to solve the incompatibility.
Building plugin apple_sign_in...
Running Gradle task 'assembleAarRelease'...

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  A problem occurred configuring root project 'apple_sign_in'.

> SDK location not found. Define location with sdk.dir in the local.properties file or with an ANDROID_HOME environment variable.

- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 5s

Exception: The plugin apple_sign_in could not be built due to the issue above.

pleas help me

Comment: Have you set sdk path cause from this seems you have not `SDK location not found. Define location with sdk.dir in the local.properties file or with an ANDROID_HOME environment variable.`

Comment: thank you 
I do it 
but I have a new assus 
BUILD FAILED in 7m 16s
The built failed likely due to AndroidX incompatibilities in a plugin. The tool is about to try using Jetfier to solve the incompatibility.
Building plugin apple_sign_in...
Running Gradle task 'assembleAarRelease'...
√ Built build\app\outputs\repo.
Building plugin cloud_firestore...
Running Gradle task 'assembleAarRelease'...
Exception: The plugin cloud_firestore could not be built due to the issue above.